# Ubuntu user does not exist probably due to kerberos issue

Tags: user-accounts, ubuntu-16.04, kerberos

I often run out of space in my file system with Ubuntu 16.04. This time after I have got the error that no space left in my drive, I have started to delete some old files. However, some errors kept occuring. In **dmesg** there was repeating BIOS errors. An icon disappeared from launch menu etc... So I decided to reboot system after making enough space.
After reboot I could not reboot anymore. Thinking of a possible security threat, I cloned my drive with dd and rescued data. 
I checked for bad sectors none found.
Now, when I login via advanced options from the GRUB to root user, I can't find any trace of my username in **/etc/passwd** or **/etc/shadow** (there is also /etc/shadow-).
**getent passwd**  gives nothing.
My user is linked to **kerberos** (for work). I am not really familiar with it.
I wonder, how can I fix the issue and login with my user?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, after logging in as root via normal login screen, I could log in into normal user. I don't know why it was possible all of a sudden. One idea I have, is that I connected to internet via root user, which might have enabled kerberos to renew tickets and user data. Now, I have another issue that apt-get tells me normal packages have untrusted sources (e.g. thunderbird).